# Regex in MongoC

Tags: mongo-c-driver

How can I do this query in mongoC with bcon_new?

```
 db.users.find({"name": /.*m.*/})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After few try and error i finally found the answer based on libbson analogy

```
bson_t *query;

query = BCON_NEW ("name", BCON_REGEX("m","i") );
```

Answer (score 2):

There is also a specialist for the bson_append_...

```
bson_append_regex(&doc, "name", -1, ".*m.*", nullptr);
cursor = mongoc_collection_find(coll, MONGOC_QUERY_NONE, 0, 0, 0, &doc, nullptr, nullptr);
```

Answer (score 1):

There is also a specialist for the bson_append_...

```
bson_append_regex(&doc, "name", -1, ".*m.*", nullptr);
```